# Component gets error this.getView is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I'm going over the sapui5 walkthrough tutorials and have managed to get to step 9 where it teaches you how to use Component.js file in your app.

Now, prior to using Component.js everything in the app was working fine. However, once I try to use component I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.getView is not a function
```

Referring to UIComponent.js line 6. Even though my component file is just called Component.js. I also get:

```
GET http://localhost:58736/InvoicesApp/invoicesapp/Component-preload.js 404 (Not Found)
```

But I'm not sure they're related

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
                data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
                data-sap-ui-preload="async"
                >
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("invoicesapp");
                sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                     new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
                           name : "invoicesapp"
                        }).placeAt("content");

                 });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"/>
</html>
```

My Component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
   "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (UIComponent,  JSONModel, ResourceModel) {
   "use strict";
   return UIComponent.extend("invoicesapp.Component", {
       metadata: {
           rootView:"invoicesapp.view.App"
       },

      init : function () {
         // call the init function of the parent
         UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
         
      // set data model on view
         var oData = {
            recipient : {
               name : "World"
            }
         };
         var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
         this.getView().setModel(oModel);
     // set i18n model on view
         var i18nModel = new ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "invoicesapp.i18n.i18n"
         });
         this.getView().setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
    }
   });
});
```

My controller

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
   "sap/m/MessageToast",
   "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
   "sap/ui/model/resource/ResourceModel"
], function (Controller, MessageToast, JSONModel, ResourceModel) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("invoicesapp.controller.App", {
    
      onShowHello : function () {
          
         // read msg from i18n model
         var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
         var sRecipient = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/recipient/name");
         var sMsg = oBundle.getText("helloMsg", [sRecipient]);
         // show message
         MessageToast.show(sMsg);
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component you can't call this.getView() because there is no getView(), the  api docs at https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html

Instead, you set the model directly on the component itself. In other words, just call

```
this.setModel(oModel);
```

and

```
this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
```

By the way: in the walktrough it's done the same way.

Comment: It worked!!! thanks so much :)
I don't know the SAP UI 5 tutorial page has this.getView()

Comment: Hi I have this.setModel(oModel); in the Component.js, and the controller like the first post, but still isnt working. I have the getView() error in the component.js . I get the button and the input (defined in my view.js), but no action on press and no input description due to the error. How can I replace the getView in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

this.getView() will not be defined in component.js as view is yet to be instantiated.

You can simply set model with just this.setModel(oModel) and you can set names model by this.setModel(oModel,"modelName");

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem while going through the walk through.

View is not instantiated in the Component.

You can rewrite as

```
this.setModel("myModel);
```

And for i18n

```
this.setModel(i18nModel,"i18n");
```

This error was there in walk through but now its fixed it seems. There were few errors with the SAP UI5 Tutorials while I was learning but they have fixed most of them now.

This is also a good source to start with UI5. Almost similar to Demokit.

[UI Development Toolkit for HTML5 (SAPUI5)](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/95/d113be50ae40d5b0b562b84d715227/content.htm?current_toc=/en/d0/1cd0b7be7f441cb6c56ad4577b428c/plain.htm&show_children=true)

Happy Coding

Febin Dominic